# Neo4j lowest common ancestor node not found

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path, genetic, lowest-common-ancestor

I have loaded a hierarchical tree (DAG) of DNA SNPs. I want to identify lowest common ancestors.

This query works, yield the single correct node:

```
Match (n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'}), (m:SNPNode{SNP:'R-BY13828'})
match path=(n)-[:SNPParent*..99]->(MRCA)<-[:SNPParent*..99]-(m) 
return MRCA.SNP
```

However, this one yields no result:

```
Match (n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'}), (m:SNPNode{SNP:'R-S25289'})
match path=(n)-[:SNPParent*..99]->(MRCA)<-[:SNPParent*..99]-(m) 
return MRCA.SNP
```

even though the two queries seeking ancestors of both yield nodes some of which are shared:

```
MATCH p=(n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'})-[r:SNPParent*..66]->(m) RETURN m.SNP

m.SNP
R-Z338
R-Z8
R-Z7
R-Z2
R-Z345
R-Z27
R-Z30
R-Z9
R-L48
R-Z301
R-Z381
R-U106
R-L151
R-L51
R-L23
R-M269
R-P297
R-L389
R-L754
R-M343
```

and

```
MATCH p=(n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z25289'})-[r:SNPParent*..66]->(m) RETURN m.SNP

m.SNP
R-S16701
R-S1774
R-Z341
**R-Z11**
R-Z338
R-Z8
R-Z7
R-Z2
R-Z345
R-Z27
R-Z30
R-Z9
R-L48
R-Z301
R-Z381
R-U106
R-L151
R-L51
R-L23
R-M269
R-P297
R-L389
R-L754
R-M343
```

It seems the problem is that R-Z11 is in the path of the second query and is itself the ancestor. In other words, sometimes the LCA is at the end of a shortest path. Is there a way to address this so that R-Z11 returns as the result where or not it is in the shortest path?

Comment: You may want to double-check the nodes in question. In the query that yielded no results, the SNPs being used are 'R-Z11' and 'R-S25289'. But the queries you used for seeking ancestors afterward were for 'R-Z11' and 'R-Z25289'. You changed the S to a Z.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to ensure your variable-length paths have a lower bound of 0 (when you omit the lower bound, as in your current queries, it defaults to 1). This will make it possible for the start and end nodes to be considered as possible matches to `MRCA`.

```
Match (n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'}), (m:SNPNode{SNP:'R-S25289'})
match path=(n)-[:SNPParent*0..99]->(MRCA)<-[:SNPParent*0..99]-(m) 
return MRCA.SNP
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, adding a lower bound of zero produced no result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that works:

```
match p=(n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'})<-[:SNPChild*0..99]-(MRCA:SNPNode)-[:SNPChild*0..99]->(m:SNPNode{SNP:'R-BY13828'}) 
return MRCA.SNP
```

Or, to get the lowest common ancestor (MRCA) with a boolean flag:

```
match p=(n:SNPNode{SNP:'R-Z11'})<-[:SNPChild*0..99]-(MRCA:SNPNode)-[:SNPChild*0..99]->(m:SNPNode{SNP:'R-BY13828'}) unwind(nodes(p)) as pn
return case when pn.SNP=MRCA.SNP then True else False end as MRCA,pn.SNP
```

with this output

MRCA    SNP

FALSE   R-Z11

FALSE   R-Z338

TRUE    R-Z8

FALSE   R-BY13828